# Join tables having multiple values in a cell

Tags: sql, join

This question was asked to me in an interview.
I have two tables as given below

Table1 :
[table1]
[image: 1]

Table2 :
[table2]
[image: 2]

I want the following table as my output. Please tell me the SQL query which can be used to join the two tables and get the output as given below.

Expected Output :
[output][image: 3]

Sorry for adding the images as I could not figure out how to add the tables

Comment: you need to tag your databse as well

Comment: @eshirvana This was the only information provided. The question was 'If you have 2 tables given as above and want the output as mentioned then what will be the sql query for that''

Comment: The question is malformed: At first, B is related to Mango/Apple but later it *magically* changed to Mango/Orange...

Comment: You add the tables as text just like you typed the question, using the comprehensive [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help. you need to tag your specific database as the solution will vary depending on the syntax supported by a particular database.

Comment: The answer should be: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS Relevant because you are a learner: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)
 [What is the policy here on homework?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18242/266284)

Comment: This is a(n easily found) faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Learn about google 'site:'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that should work in the majority of databases just uses `like` to match on the strings.

Also note the sample data is incorrect for B - *Orange* does not appear in the results.

```
select t1.name, t2.fruit, t2.value
from t1 join t2 on t1.fruits like Concat('%',t2.fruit,'%')
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me how can we insert the comma separated values in a table as given in table1?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the above answers the question which is how to get the output from the two source tables. I have no idea how you arrived at the comma separated values, that's your source data, and as pointed out already, is *not* a good idea, data in a column should always be *atomic*

Comment: Thank you. I am getting the expected output from the given query.